# Is there a way to quickly download data from a pbix?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have recently started working in Power BI. A big part of my job is data validation, and I am working with very large data sets, 30M+ rows. Is there a way to download the entire raw data, or automate a download of multiple files, filtering off one or several columns?

Ex:

A company has 500 stores, the dataset contains each transaction for each store, I want to download the transactions for each store. Do I have to do this manually?

I am pretty sure there is no way to download the entire dataset, but if there is a way to automate downloading it in many parts, that would be nice.

Thanks

The only way I have found to export tabular data is to literally copy and paste it from the table view, which of course does not work if there are too many rows as excel can't handle that many. I have to first filter based on several columns, then copy out the data and work with it in either excel or python.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the dataset directly in Excel. In the Data tab in the ribbon, Get Data > From Power Platform > From Power BI. From here you can set-up your filters etc...

If you have a Pro licence, then you can also connect to the dataset via XMLA endpoint. Then you can use Python or any other tool to connect to it. [Connect to Power BI XMLA endpoint with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347765/connect-to-power-bi-xmla-endpoint-with-python)

Another option is to connect to dataset from a local Power BI file and do your analysis in Power BI. You can create new measures on top of that in the dataset .